# Is there a Python command that returns the string sandwiched between two identifiers?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm scraping values from web page html that looks like this:

```
location=1">MAIN BUILDING</a> : -25.49<br />
```

I'm successfully using Python's partition twice: once to save everything after the ID string `MAIN BUILDING</a> :` and then again to save the part before `<br />`

Using partition twice doesn't seem too horrible. But is there a better way to do this?  Seems like there ought to be a way to extract a string sandwiched between between two other strings in one step rather than two.

Comment: I suspect that the feature you want is a "regular expression", using the "capture" feature.  Those should be enough for you to find an example on line, and avoid getting any answer disqualified for being a "duplicate".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: [Get a parser.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) It'll be much more effective and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.index` with Python string indexing for a one-liner:

```
>>> s = 'location=1">MAIN BUILDING</a> : -25.49<br />'
>>> begin = 'MAIN BUILDING</a> :'
>>> end = '<br />'
>>> s[s.index(begin):s.index(end)]
'MAIN BUILDING</a> : -25.49'
```

This assumes many things:

1. The exact text that you included will delimit the string in question.
2. Both pieces of text occur exactly once.